# Serve images from subdomain in Wordpress

Tags: sql, wordpress, image, woocommerce, subdomain

to give you some context with where I'm at, I have set up a subdomain to serve the images for my site on `www.images.mysite.com`

This "images" subdomain is intended to serve the images to primary domain `www.mysite.com` (being located on the server at "/public_html") and also the Woocommerce subdomain `www.shop.mysite.com` (being located on the server at "/public_html/shop").

I have uploaded the images from the old directory (which is currently still in use) on the server at "/public_html/wp-content/uploads" to the new directory connected to the `www.images.mysite.com` subdomain at "/public_html/images/wp-content/uploads"

The challenges I'm facing at this stage is that I can't seem to get the images to upload to the `www.images.mysite.com` location when sent from the `www.mysite.com` Wordpress installation or the `www.shop.mysite.com` Wordpress installation even after adding the path for this to 'options.php' for both the `www.mysite.com` Wordpress installation or `www.shop.mysite.com` Wordpress installations.

When I did set this path earlier though 'options.php' (through `www.mysite.com/wp-admin/options.php` pointing to `www.images.mysite.com` without the trailing slash) it caused conflicts with the `www.mysite.com` and `www.shop.mysite.com` sites and dropped all the images from both the `www.mysite.com` Wordpress installation and the [www.shop.mysite.com](http://www.shop.mysite.com) Wordpress installations. When I removed the path from the ‘options.php’ file the installations both worked fine again.

I have had the process of setting this up explained to me as:

*Imagine you want the images for `www.shop.mysite.com` to be loaded from `www.images.mysite.com` The document root folder for `www.shop.mysite.com` is /public_html/shop - for the images it's /public_html/shop/wp-content **(Note: I think this is supposed to be /public_html/images/wp-content but correct me if I'm wrong)**.

In such case, we need to change the document root for `www.images.mysite.com` to that one -> public_html/shop/wp-content. Once done, inside the wp-config.php for `www.shop.mysite.com`, you would need to add the following code: `define("WP_CONTENT_URL", "http:// images.mysite.com"); define("COOKIE_DOMAIN", "shop.mysite.com");`  Once done, from phpmyadmin, in the database for `www.shop.mysite.com` (XXXXXX21_wp451) -> there is a tool named SQL at the top where you can run queries. This would be the needed query `-> UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content,'www. shop.mysite.com/wp-content/','images.mysite.com/')`*

The explanation above seems a bit out to me with the note I added as bolded.

I'm running HTTPS - should the code above state that?

There are some spaces in what I have been provided here that I'm not sure if they will have an impact on the execution.

I have a dummy site that I can use which won't cause any major issues if I break it which i'll test this in. If anyone has any pointers they would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

take a backup for your database and files and do as this [article](https://www.webnots.com/move-wordpress-images-folder-to-subdomain/) explains:

> Login to your hosting account and launch “phpMyAdmin” section under cPanel. Open the database of your main domain. Select “wp-options” table and replace the following two parameters and save your settings.

```
upload_path      ==>    directory root for your subdomain
upload_url_path  ==>    actual URL path for your subdomain
```

> Until this step there will be no impact on your live site since the existing media upload folder is not changed. Any new image you upload henceforth will be stored in a new subdomain path you have entered in the “wp-options” table. You can cross check this by uploading a test image and check the URL. Once you modified the upload path in “wp-options” table you can see the upload path options are enabled in WordPress admin frontend under “Settings > Media“. Henceforth you can update the uploads file path directly here.

then you will have to replace images links by running this SQL query:

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content,'URL of current media folder','URL of new media folder')
```